# Mongoose 4 to 5: connection.db.collection() undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to upgrade from Mongoose 4.x to 5.x. So far the biggest issue I'm running in to is after the database has connected I'm unable to fetch collections like I was able to in 4.x.

```
const someCollection = mongoose.connection.db.collection('someCollection');
```

This code works fine in 4.x, but apparently the underlying structure of Mongoose has changed between versions.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Mongoose 5.x? I looked in the documentation and the migration guide but didn't see anything.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you @JohnnyHK!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Mongoose 5.x, the `.db` part isn't needed so it should be:

```
mongoose.connection.collection('someCollection');
```

Comment: There is also a guide available for migrating to version 5 : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html